# What is a more efficient way to do a nested if statement in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I have a code similar to the one shown below, and I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to code this method in mvc.

```
  public ActionResult LogViewerFiles([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string testValue, string testValue2)

    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testValue2) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testValue))
        {
            return View();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testValue))
        {
           var fileName = testValue;
           var logEntries = LogEntry.ReadLogEntries(fileName);

            if (logEntries == null)
            {
                return JavaScript("Callback()");                  
            }
            return Json(logEntries.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        if (testValue2!= null)
        {
            var resultPath = testValue2;
            var logEntriesArch = LogEntry.ReadLogEntries(resultPath);
            return Json(logEntriesArch.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Basically what I am attempting to achieve is to execute different if statements, depending on the value of my arguments. In this case, only one argument will have the information I need to execute the code, and the other argument will always be null. This method is written so all the information gathered can be displayed in a kendo razor grid.

Comment: Define "efficient".

Comment: Well you don't need the `fileName` or `resultPath` variables.  Just pass `testValue` and `testValue2` to `LogEntry.ReadLogEntries`.

Comment: I see quite a few problems with your code that should be refactored.  If it compiles and is working, I would suggest you post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question looks like it might be a pretty good fit for [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), provided that (a) you want _every aspect_ of your code reviewed, not just some, (b) your code is _already working_, and (c) you're asking for a review of _concrete, real code_, not abstract design (whether or not it's expressed as code). If you agree with all of those, please read about [what's on topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and, if your question fits that, delete it here and repost it on CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While an overkill (you *do* have a design problem in your code), you could refactor you code in a dispatcher.

See this LINQPad example:

```
public void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.YourAction("foo", "bar"));
    Console.WriteLine(this.YourAction("foo", "baz"));
}

public string YourAction(string firstParameter, string secondParameter)
{
    var handler = Dispatcher.GetHandler(firstParameter, secondParameter);

    if (handler == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("I don't know what to do.");
    }

    return handler.Handle(firstParameter, secondParameter);
}

public static class Dispatcher
{
    private readonly static ICollection<Handler> Handlers = new List<Handler>();

    static Dispatcher()
    {
        Handlers.Add(new FooHandler());
        Handlers.Add(new BarHandler());
    }

    public static Handler GetHandler(string firstParameter, string secondParameter)
    {
        // Yes, Single, not First. If you screw up and two handlers can handle
        // the same parameters set you want to know it up front, not later.
        return Handlers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.CanHandle(firstParameter, secondParameter));
    }
}

public abstract class Handler
{
    public abstract bool CanHandle(string firstParameter, string secondParameter);

    public abstract string Handle(string firstParameter, string secondParameter);
}

public class FooHandler : Handler
{
    public override bool CanHandle(string firstParameter, string secondParameter)
    {
        return firstParameter == "foo" && secondParameter == "bar";
    }

    public override string Handle(string firstParameter, string secondParameter)
    {
        return "FooAction";
    }
}

public class BarHandler : Handler
{
    public override bool CanHandle(string firstParameter, string secondParameter)
    {
        return firstParameter == "foo" && secondParameter == "baz";
    }

    public override string Handle(string firstParameter, string secondParameter)
    {
        return "BarAction";
    }
}
```

Every handler tells the dispatcher if it can handle the supplied parameters, the dispatcher picks the correct one and then runs it.

Comment: this might seem overkill, but I'd agree that if you need to run nested conditionals in your controller in order to find out what action to REALLY take, you either have a very complex system and a dispatcher might be warranted, or you need to rethink your architecture really badly.